# Entity Framework 4: How to extend an entity?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have imported database tables to `.edmx` file and among the others I have a `Customer` entity like:

```
CustID
CustName
CustAddress
```

Now I want to allow the user to edit the selected customers and I need to show the number of orders each customer has, so upon showing the edition form I need to add a field dynamically to this entity - field `CustOrderCount` which will evaluate a sql statement `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders WHERE CustomerID = {id}`.

Is there a way to extend the entity somehow so the order count is selected by EF **without** manually doing a custom select like this:

```
.Select(c => new CustomerExtended 
{ 
    CustID = c.CustID, 
    ... 
    CustOrderCount = db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderCustID = c.CustID).Count()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the project where your edmx file live, create a new `partial` `class`:

```
public partial class Customer {}
```

You can then add your own properties/methods to the EF entity:

```
public partial class Customer {
   public int GetSomething(){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Entity retrieves from database only fields which are in the table itself. For this purpose you must either do a projection as you showed, use custom data retrieval as @Jason showed.

The projection to custom view model is correct solution in this case because you want to show some additional data which are not part of your entity.

Answer (score 0):

You can to create a view into your database, map it as your entity, and to use triggers to deal with CRUD operations.